# Discord.py Attribute Error using youtube_dl?

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl

This is my code:

```
    channel = client.get_channel(myid) 
    vc = await channel.connect()
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.volume = 0.5
    player.start()
```

And i get:

```
AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), specifically the [Voice Changes section](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#voice-changes):

> - create_ffmpeg_player/create_stream_player/create_ytdl_player have all been removed.
>
>   - The goal is to create [AudioSource](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AudioSource) instead.